# Angularjs UI.router not displaying the initial template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angularjs application using ui-router, when i access the following URL **http://localhost:63342/UIRouter/customlogin**, as per the ui-route configured it has to display the customlogin.html page but its not, it gives 404 error page

in the above url UIRouter is the application name and /customlogin is the state's url.

could somebody help me in getting this solved...please

below is the plnkr url

https://plnkr.co/edit/SPOr9IUWWSAIxNbfnBox?p=preview

below are my files

**baseApp.js**

```
angular.module('baseApp',['baseApp.routes']);
```

**baseApp.routes.js**

```
angular.module('baseApp.routes',['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$httpProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider){

    console.log("in view");
    $stateProvider
        .state("login",{
            url:'/customlogin',
            templateUrl:'customlogin.html',
            controller:'ContactLoginCtrl'
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/customlogin");
}]) ;
```

**ContactLoginCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('baseApp')
.controller('ContactLoginCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
    console.log("in the controller")

}])
```

**customlogin.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="baseApp">
<body>
<form name="contactLogin" ng-controller="ContactLoginCtrl"  ng-submit="authenticate(userModel)">
    <label  for="name" >UserName:</label>
    <input  type="text" ng-model="userModel.username" /></br>
    </br>

    <label for="password" >PassWord:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="userModel.password"  />
    </br>
    </br>
    <button type="submit"  name="Login" >Login</button>

</form>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="baseApp.js"></script>
<script src="baseApp.routes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Among other adjustments,* the most important is - to have a **target** for states. We need:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

There is [adjusted and working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Niu3WHhZkODXeY0uCXYy?p=preview)